# Using abstractions to make a translator

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Given

```
class Allocator {
  public:
   virtual char *allocate(unsigned int size)=0;
      // EFF: allocates a character buffer of size characters
    virtual void dispose(char *buf)=0;
      // REQ: buf was allocated by this allocator
      // EFF: release memory previously allocated.
};
class Translator {
  public:
    virtual char *operator()(const char *s, Allocator &a) = 0;
      // EFF: returns a translation of the C-string s as
      //      another C-string, where the translation 
      //      C-string is allocated by a.
};
```

Suppose you want to implement the following:

```
void printTranslatedArgs(int argc, char *argv[], 
                         Translator &t, Allocator &a);
  // REQ: argc/argv are in the form of program arguments
  // EFF: prints the translated command line.
```

I'm having trouble understanding how this works since allocate, dispose, and operator are pure virtual, so they're respective classes don't actually define those functions.

Answer (score 3):

References support polymorphism. This means that whoever is using the function `printTranslatedArgs` will need to call it with base classes of `Translator` and `Allocator` which implement all the virtual functions. You dont need to bother about the concrete class type inside the function, call them as if they are any other member functions, for e.g:

```
char *p = a.allocate(5);
```

Comment: How do I actually call them here, though?

Comment: You would use it as if they have function definitions. `char *p = a.allocate(5)`, etc

Answer (score 2):

The

```
void printTranslatedArgs(int argc, char *argv[], 
                         Translator &t, Allocator &a);
```

means that any classes that implement the methods in Translator/Allocator can be used.

IOW one can say that the abstract classes define a contract (interface) and derived classes must implement those methods in order to fullfill the contract.

e.g. MyTranslator implements the virtual method `char* operator()`

```
class MyTranslator : public Translator
{
public:
virtual char *operator()(const char *s, Allocator &a) { /*...*/ }
};

// omitted decl/def of MyAllocator

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
  MyTranslator foo;
  MyAllocator bar;
  printTranslatedArgs(argc,argv,foo,bar);
  ...
}
```